# Error creating bean with name 'CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:

Tags: tomcat8, postgresql-9.6

I'm having the error that I think is connected to PostgreSQL-Tomcat connection. I was not able to locate the piece where I am mistaken:

**My catalina.out:**

```
    23.10.2020 14:45:27.207 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean' while setting bean property 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DatabaseConfiguration' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'psqlDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    ...........
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DatabaseConfiguration' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'psqlDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
    .........
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'psqlDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

My applicationcontext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="psqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/freshSiteDS"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="psqlDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="psqlDataSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="psqlDataSource"/>
        <property name="initOnMigrate" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="psqlDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="namedJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="psqlDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
        <property name="propertyNamingStrategy" value="#{T(org.codehaus.jackson.map.PropertyNamingStrategy).CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES}" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder file-encoding="UTF-8" properties-ref="CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

    <bean name="CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean"
          class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="DatabaseConfiguration"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="DatabaseConfiguration"
          class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration" depends-on="flyway">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="psqlDataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="st_application_properties"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="property_key"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="property_value"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="kernel-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="service-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="security-context2.xml"/>
    <import resource="ws-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="settings-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="migration-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="search-context.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**The JDBC driver is in /opt/tomcat/lib/postgresql-42.2.18.jar**

**Please, give some piece of advice**

Comment: "*Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory*" -- you are missing the the DBCP classes in your Tomcat libraries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, is this what I need:
/opt/tomcat/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
?